# How to Filter List By Comparing between two lists and if an id exist on second list then take the value from second list otherwise first list?

Tags: java, spring-boot, arraylist, compare

I have two list appIndustries and tenantAppIndustries both having List of values:

```
    List<String> industries = new ArrayList<>();
    List<AppIndustryDto> appIndustries ;
    List<AppIndustryDto> tenantAppIndustries ;

    public class AppIndustryDto {
    public String appId;
    public String industryId;
   }
```

Both Lists have data. Inside the appIndustries list I am getting:

```
  a1 i1
  a1 i2
  a2 i3
  a3 i1
```

Inside tenantAppIndustries list I am getting:

```
 a1 i4
```

Final Response should be industries list and should have [i1,i3,i4]

Comment: Hint: You could use a simple `for` loop to go through the list and do an `if` check to see if you take the varue from the first or second list, then simply save that value to a new list that you can use your your final response.

Comment: can you show me with code ? So I can better understand please ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<AppIndustryDto> appIndustries = List.of(
        new AppIndustryDto("a1", "i1"),
        new AppIndustryDto("a1", "i2"),
        new AppIndustryDto("a2", "i3"),
        new AppIndustryDto("a3", "i1"));

    List<AppIndustryDto> tenantAppIndustries = List.of(
        new AppIndustryDto("a1", "i4"));

    Map<String, String> tenantMap = tenantAppIndustries.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(a -> a.appId, a -> a.industryId, (a, b) -> a));
        // If the appId is duplicated, select the first one.

    List<String> industries = appIndustries.stream()
        .map(a -> tenantMap.getOrDefault(a.appId, a.industryId))
        .distinct()
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

    System.out.println(industries);
}
```

output:

```
[i4, i3, i1]
```

Comment: Inside tenantMap appId is having only one IndustryId but appId can have multiple industryId so, it's similar to appIndustries like
List<AppIndustryDto> tenantAppIndustries = List.of(
        new AppIndustryDto("a1", "i4"));
        new AppIndustryDto("a1", "i2"),

Thanks for your answer and also it's giving error in the .toList()

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
List<String> list = appIndustries.stream()
.map(app -> {
  AppIndustryDto dto = tenantAppIndustries.stream()
                              .filter(t -> t.appId.equals(app.appId))
                              .findAny()
                              .orElse(null);
  return dto==null ? app.industryId : dto.industryId ;
})
.distinct()
.collect(Collectors.toList());
```